# how to get opencv_contrib module in anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

Can anyone tell me commands to get contrib module for anaconda

I need that module for 
 matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
to run correctly

error thrown is 
cv2.error: ......\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:163: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate

Also I am using Anaconda openCV version 3, and strictly dont want to switch to lower versions 
P.S. as suggested at many places to edit file cv2.cpp option is not available with anaconda.

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anaconda supports `pip install` to install package into `conda` environment. You can download `OpenCV 3.2.0` with `opencv_contrib` from this well known [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) website. See the filename below for the right version. Then type the command in `Anaconda Prompt` window to install the package:

For Python 3.5 and 64-bit Windows:

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

For Python 3.6 and 64-bit Windows:

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Most of the `OpenCV 3.2.0` packages in Anaconda repository didn't specific if they come with `opencv_contrib`. The `pip install` approach is easier and proven, see [one of the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2/43190144#43190144). The only drawback is that `conda list` will not show `pip` installed package there but actually it's.

However, if you want to have trial on `conda install`, below is the command for installing `OpenCV 3.2.0` for Python 3.5 or 3.6 but likely **without** `opencv_contrib`.

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Is the same for Ubuntu??

Comment: @ChachoFuva I haven't tried the command in Ubuntu. You may have a trial.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend installing `pip` in your Anaconda environment, and then just doing: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.
This comes with `opencv` and `opencv-contrib`.

Comment: Awesome! I think this tops `brew install` and `conda install` methods! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can try this: https://anaconda.org/michael_wild/opencv-contrib

> To install this package with conda run:
>
> ```
> conda install -c michael_wild opencv-contrib
> ```

These anaconda packages include the `contrib` modules with base OpenCV3. Though the file list says it's currently for Windows only!

Comment: Please add the relevant details from your link to your post.  If the link changes, your post will not help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I thought to update the answer with the latest information. My Anaconda version is 2019.10 and build channel is py_37_0 . I  used `pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17`. Now they are also visible as installed packages in Anaconda navigator and I am able to use patented methods like SIFT etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**: in Anaconda Prompt write this, will install opencv-contrib v4.6

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

**Method 2**: Install previous version of opencv-contrib v3.3.1

According to  https://anaconda.org/michael_wild/opencv-contrib it says it support win64bit only and python 3.6.x.

So, first you need to create new enviroment support python 3.6

```
conda create --opencv_contrib36 python=3.6.13
```

then, install the packages

```
conda install -c michael_wild opencv-contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

There is repo in conda-forge which includes `opencv-contrib`: https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

To use it:

```
conda install --channel=conda-forge libopencv opencv py-opencv
```

if you run into Numpy error, try pinning more recent version (of Numpy).

Comment: is `py-opencv` the `opencv-contrib` equivalent?

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me in Windows 10 on Anaconda 5.3 with python 3.6

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```