# DLL load failed error when importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed opencv on my windows machine using python 3.6 without any issues, using:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

but when I try to import cv2 I get the following error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200025/cant-import-cv2-dll-load-failed)

It says cv2 doesn't work with python 3 I was wondering if this has been fixed or if there is a way around it

Comment: The latest supported version of python in OpenCV is 3.5 not 3.6

Comment: @kmario23: I tried with Python 3.5.0 and I still get the same error.

Comment: Check out the answer of @tientuyen07, it works for me. For python3.7.0 on Windows10.

Comment: Note cv2 definitely works with Python3 nobody should be using Python 2 any more! :)

Comment: I had it installed with conda. After uninstalling it and reinstalling using pip, it worked.

Comment: Installing for Anaconda you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196320/installing-opencv-with-conda-and-spyder) which helped me.

Comment: Just run `pip install opencv-python` should work. I am using python38.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can download the latest OpenCV 3.2.0 for Python 3.6 on Windows 32-bit or 64-bit machine, look for file starts with`opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m`,  from this [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). Then type below command to install it:

- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` (32-bit version)
- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` (64-bit version)

I think it would be easier.

**Update on 2017-09-15:**

`OpenCV 3.3.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and replaced `OpenCV 3.2.0`.

**Update on 2018-02-15:**

`OpenCV 3.4.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and replaced `OpenCV 3.3.0`.

**Update on 2018-06-19:**

`OpenCV 3.4.1` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support, and replaced `OpenCV 3.4.0`.

**Update on 2018-10-03:**

`OpenCV 3.4.3` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support, and replaced `OpenCV 3.4.1`.

**Update on 2019-01-30:**

`OpenCV 4.0.1` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support.

**Update on 2019-06-10:**

`OpenCV 3.4.6` and `OpenCV 4.1.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support.

**Update on 2023-02-11:**

`OpenCV 4.5.5` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.7/3.8/3.9/3.10/3.11` support.

Comment: AN UPDATE: `opencv3.2.0` with `opencv_contrib` binaries for `Python 3.5 and 3.6` are now available for download from the [unoffice site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). Look for entry consists of `+contrib` in the file name. For example, `opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: Requirement 'opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Comment: It looks that `opencv 3.2 for python 3.x` are removed after my UPDATE. You may use `opencv 3.3`.

Comment: A note for those who don't know, like I didn't: the `cp` in filenames there stands for CPython, so the number after that is your Python version.

Comment: Installed sucessfully, but got same error. File name `opencv_python-4.5.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`, python `3.10.0`, win11x64

Comment: I instralled successfully, but now have some error of "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import", despite numpy actual version installed. Maybe it's some specific version needed, idk.

Comment: @Peter.k See the update on `2023-02-11` above.

Comment: will you please collapse all those "updates"? and prefix the entire post with a clear statement that you refer to builds by "Christoph Gohlke". "unofficial site" is meaningless. and while you're at it, please remove all mentions of outdated versions. I just had someone show up wondering why "3.2.0" is old. there is no reason to keep updating this post at all.

Answer (score 87):

I took a lot of time to solve this error! 
Run command

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: There are several issue about this question, but I find it's platform is not Windos10 + Python3.7.0. And your answer is works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: worked for me. I had installed opencv-python and some else, but this was the final thing.

Comment: Works for win7 pyhton3.7.3 (Anaconda) - Thanks

Comment: Worked for me in a conda environment with python = 3.7.10

Comment: This works sometimes for me

Comment: working with python 3.8 as of 2023. Installed camelot using `` conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py" and then used this solution.

Answer (score 38):

If you are using Anaconda with `python 3.5`, this is a problem in the Anaconda release. (Refer this [issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36))

You can fix this issue by copying `python3.dll` file to `Anaconda3` folder (where `python.exe` is located)

#### How to get "python3.dll"

- In `cmd`, type `python --version` to find whether your installation is 64-bit or 32-bit
- download python 3.x embeddable zip file from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
- Extract the zip file and copy `python3.dll` file to `Anaconda3` folder

But if you can move to `Anaconda` with `python 3.6` you will not face this issue. If it is possible for you, then it is the recommended way..

Comment: it works great... after spending 4 hrs, came to this post... helped me alot. currently using Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64 with Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Answer (score 28):

Recently I have faced the similar issue in Azure **Windows Server 2012 r2** . Tried all option with and without Anaconda but none of them helped. After lot of findings I found that **mfplat.dll** was missing which is related to Window Media Service.

Hence you have to manually install the features so that you can get dll related to window media service.

1.Turn windows features on or off

2.Skip the roles screen and directly go to Feature screen

3.Select "Desktop Experience" under "User Interfaces and Infrastructure"

After this all required dll of media services for opencv would be available.

So if you are planning to run your code in cloud(Window Server) then please dont forget to select Desktop Experience feature.

Comment: It worked for me on Windows Server 2012. Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks for this answer! You saved me a lot of time and it worked perfectly on my Win2012R2!

Comment: Running  Windows Server 2012 R2 on AWS, and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! perfectly worked in Win2012R2 edition.

Comment: Really thankful for this.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this problem on **Windows 10 (N)** with a new Anaconda installation based on Python 3.7 (OpenCV version 4.0). None of the above advice helped (such as installing OpenCV from the unofficial site nor installing VC Redistributable).

I checked DLL dependencies of `...\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\foo\Lib\site-packages\cv2\cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` using `dumpbin.exe` according to [this github issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36). I noticed a library `MF.dll`, which I figured out belongs to Windows Media Foundation.

So I **installed** [**Media Feature Pack** for N versions of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) and voilà, the issue was resolved!

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me (Python 3.6 + OpenCv 3.4). I think the Media Feature Pack might be uninstalled during some major windows update

Comment: This was my issue and I don't use Anaconda. There's about 5 missing DLLs if the Media feature pack is not installed. You can go to Settings -> Apps -> Apps & Features then click on "Optional Features" and "+ Add a feature" to install the Media Feature Pack.

Comment: And also there is way to install via [powershell dism](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/170733-installing-windows-media-feature-pack-post2111775.html#post2111775), in my case lifesaver since recommended MS or KB methods did not work

Answer (score 9):

After spending too much time on this issue and trying out all different answers, here is what found:

- The accepted answer by @thewaywewere is no longer applicable. I think this was applicable when opencv-python module still wasn't available.
- This is indeed a bug in Anaconda 4.2 because they forgot to ship python3.dll. They have fixed this in next releases but unfortunately 4.2 is the last release with Python 3.5 as default. If you are stuck with Python 3.5 (for example VS2015 is only aware of versions up to 3.5) then you must manually download python3.dll as described in answer by @Ramesh-X.
- If you can move on to Python 3.6 (which at present bit difficult if you are using OpenCV and VS2015) then just install latest Anaconda version and you don't have to deal with any of these.

Comment: Anaconda bug has been resolved. Best feedback I found on [opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and I wrote the [troubleshooting of opencv-dll-load-failed](https://programming-review.com/python/opencv-dll-load-failed) afterwords.

Answer (score 5):

There are many questions on that and many suggestions. None of them helped me for the recent Opencv 3.4.16 and Python 3.6/3.7. 
Finally I switched to Pyhon 2.7.15 and installed opencv 3.1.0. The DLL-problem was solved.

When I look in cv2.pyd with dependency walker, the 3.1 has no dependency to one missing dll. Opencv 3.4 **has** this missing dependency to this dll:

```
API-MS-WIN-DOWNLEVEL-SHLWAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
```

may be this is the problem.

P.S.: I have Win7 pofessional 64Bit, 32Bit Python 2.7.15

Comment: None of the other answers helped but this one did. Rolling back opencv-python from 3.4 to 3.1.0.5 worked

Comment: Thanxx brother this is the best solution. Those who got the same error don't degrade the version just paste this dll file in system32 and systemWOW64

Answer (score 4):

Frankly there are a lot of very smart and complicated answers here. Mine is dumb and simple. I deleted my conda environment, re-installed from scratch, taking pains to *install opencv first*. This fixed my problems. Environments are meant to be temporary and diaphanous -- don't get too attached.

So if my environment was called `fubar` first make sure every instance is deactivated (including any IDEs that are using it). Then remove it:

```
conda remove --name fubar --all
```

Now I simply recreate my environment and add opencv first:

```
conda create --name fubar
conda activate fubar
conda install opencv
```

And then go from there. First open python and make sure `import cv2` works. Then you should be on your way. Note I always (*always*) install Spyder last as it tends to screw things up when I don't.

Note, if that doesn't work, we have had some cases where people have to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda, and then things worked. Obviously a last resort.

Answer (score 4):

In my case a major update of Windows 10 removed some Windows packages, so other methods (reinstalling opencv etc.) did not help. To fix it, install:

a) [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

b) [Media Feature Pack for N versions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) - needed only if you have Windows 10 N

Both need restart of PC.

Answer (score 2):

this happens because the compiler or the interpreter is finding more than one package of the file, delete all the number of same package you have and then keep only one and then try to install. It serves

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the missing `python3.dll` file in Anaconda3.

To fix the issue, you should simply copy the `python3.dll` to `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3` (or wherever your *Anaconda3* is installed).

You can get the `python3.dll` by downloading the binaries provided at the bottom of the [Python's Release page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) and extracting the `python3.dll` from the ZIP file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with python 3.6(Anaconda3) and OpenCV 3.4.1 for spyder to work. Even after copying cv2.pyd into Anaconda3 Users/home/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages, it didn't work.

But found a solution

Later I installed OpenCV and Dlib on Anaconda and copied the generated cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd and dlib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd into Anaconda3 Users/home/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages. These can be copied from environment folder C:\Users\home\Anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages.

Finally spyder started to work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to install an older version of openCV (windows 10, Python 3.6.8)

```
pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by missing the following dll
[image]

To have this dll install:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack
as already explained above

Answer (score 1):

Running python 3.8.8 from windows 10 powershell from an anaconda 4.10.1 environment I installed opencv with

conda install opencv

I could import opencv no problem when I launched python from the command line.

However, when I tried to run code from inside pydev using the python interpreter for the specific anaconda environment I had activated, pydev couldn't find whichever dll it was looking for when importing opencv.

Setting the following environment variable resolved the issue:

CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1

Source:  [PyDev/Eclipse not loading _mklinit when run from a Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974444/pydev-eclipse-not-loading-mklinit-when-run-from-a-conda-environment)

Which points to this trouble shooting description for a different library loading issue: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it seems openCV requires Windows Media Feature pack which is not installed on Windows 10 N by default, please install it using the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work by installing python 3.9.12 in a *new* environment (using conda), and then installing opencv in that environment. Because of my python version, opencv version 4.5.5 was installed instead of version 4.60.

(I had already updated VC2015-2022 and added the python3.dll to PATH; neither of these worked.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when installing opencv 2.4.13 on Anaconda3 (Python 3.6)... I managed to fix this issue by reverting to Anaconda2 (Python 2.7)

Comment: `cv2` doesn't mean `OpenCV 2.x.x`. To use `OpenCV 3.x.x`, has to `import cv2`. `OpenCV2.x.x` is relatively old, seems no one compiled it for `Python 3.x` and upload to [Anaconda Repository](https://anaconda.org/). Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994813/installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6/43022332#43022332) on the [file page](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) to find out the `OpenCV` and supported `Python` version.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. when I install WinPython programming, and run opencv after copy the cv2.pyd file from my opencv directory, it will be like this: C:\Users.....\Downloads\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64, x64 or x86 is depend on your 32 or 64 bit devices. and paste to C:\Users.....\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.4.1Qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\Lib\site-packages, I prefer the previous python 3.5 than 3.6. Because when I "import cv2" installed (python 3.6) it shows directly: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"
Then I install python 3.5 and open WinPyhton Command prompt and type "pip install opencv-python".

The command prompt download opencv automatically, it shows the process like this "Successfully installed opencv-python-3.3.0.10"

Finally, I try to run open cv by type "import cv2", it works
i try to type "cv2.**version**", and shows: '3.3.0'

Comment: I think the right answer is open cv isn't supported in py-3.6. (based on comment on the question). Also, there is lot of formatting options out here.. for example, you could say `import cv2` instead of "import cv2". just use ` for quotes.. welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Under Winpython : the `Winpython-64bit-.../python_.../DLLs` directory the file `cv2.pyd` should be renamed to `_cv2.pyd`

Answer (score 0):

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install C:\Users\Todd\Downloads\opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2

I ran this command from anaconda terminal after I downloaded the version from 
https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files

This is the only way I could get cv2 to work and I tried everything for two days.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone, on official python 3.6 windows docker image, to make this thing work I had to copy following libraries from my desktop:

C:\windows\system32

```
aepic.dll
avicap32.dll
avifil32.dll
avrt.dll
Chakra.dll
CompPkgSup.dll
CoreUIComponents.dll
cryptngc.dll
dcomp.dll
devmgr.dll
dmenterprisediagnostics.dll
dsreg.dll
edgeIso.dll
edpauditapi.dll
edputil.dll
efsadu.dll
efswrt.dll
ELSCore.dll
evr.dll
ieframe.dll
ksuser.dll
mf.dll
mfasfsrcsnk.dll
mfcore.dll
mfnetcore.dll
mfnetsrc.dll
mfplat.dll
mfreadwrite.dll
mftranscode.dll
msacm32.dll
msacm32.drv
msvfw32.dll
ngcrecovery.dll
oledlg.dll
policymanager.dll
RTWorkQ.dll
shdocvw.dll
webauthn.dll
WpAXHolder.dll
wuceffects.dll
```

C:\windows\SysWOW64

```
aepic.dll
avicap32.dll
avifil32.dll
avrt.dll
Chakra.dll
CompPkgSup.dll
CoreUIComponents.dll
cryptngc.dll
dcomp.dll
devmgr.dll
dsreg.dll
edgeIso.dll
edpauditapi.dll
edputil.dll
efsadu.dll
efswrt.dll
ELSCore.dll
evr.dll
ieframe.dll
ksuser.dll
mfasfsrcsnk.dll
mfcore.dll
mfnetcore.dll
mfnetsrc.dll
mfplat.dll
mfreadwrite.dll
mftranscode.dll
msacm32.dll
msvfw32.dll
oledlg.dll
policymanager.dll
RTWorkQ.dll
shdocvw.dll
webauthn.dll
wuceffects.dll`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Remember if you want to install python package/libraries for windows,

you should always consider [Python unofficial Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

**Step 1:**

Search for your package, download dependent version 2.7 or 3.6 you can find it under Downloads/your_package_version.whl its called `python wheel`

**Step 2:**

Now install using pip,

```
pip install ~/Downloads/your_packae_ver.whl
```

this will install without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent 3 full days wrestling with it. I tried everything suggested: upgrading pip, updating Visual C++, updating Anaconda, manually downloading files and basically every solution I could find on the web. Here's what finally worked maybe it'll help someone else:

**1-** I ditched Python 3 and Anaconda-based downloads since I noticed they had several problems and downloaded Python 2.7.16 64-bits instead.

**2-** Navigated to where Pip was located on my drive (for me the path is C:\Python27\Scripts) highlighted the path by selecting it, and typed "cmd" then enter so the Command Prompt opens on that path (I noticed skipping this usually brings about a couple errors)

**3-** Updated Pip using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` on the CMD (again, skipping this and not updating it didn't let this procedure go through)

**4-** Downloaded the appropriate `Wheel` file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv (after trying several the one that worked for me was opencv_python-2.4.13.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl) I copy-pasted it to the same folder Pip was in (C:\Python27\Scripts for me) and then installed it through CMD using: `pip install opencv_python-2.4.13.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`. Always through CMD opened on that path as showed in step 2

**5-** After step 4 when I imported OpenCV using `import cv2` I didn't have the DLL error anymore but an error related to numpy (since I had just installed that version of Python and so Numpy wasn't installed yet). I installed numpy by typing `pip install numpy` and voilà ! The problem was solved and OpenCV imported correctly.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server or docker enviroment without a gui (e.g. Windows Core Server) make sure that you use the headless version of cv2:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 N

This a final fix for the people who don't use anaconda.

simply there are missing DLL files, that's it

download the latest version of

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

Then after you extract it search for .dll files and copy all of them and paste into C:\Windows\System32 and approve for replacing.

That's it !

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 with virtual environment based python (3.11.4) scripts I managed to have OpenCV 4.8.1.78 installed with the following command -

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Please note that for some reason this installed win_amd64 version. So far it has worked well!!

Answer (score -4):

Install python using:

- pip install opencv-python(It will take the latest version)

Make sure opencv-python is installed in path(\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages),
you will find cv2 folder over there.

To check the version of cv2:
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)