# Why Import cv2 show error in python 3.6.0 on Anaconda3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed OpenCV using  command

```
pip install OpenCV-python
```

in python 3.6.0
 but shows error when I used in code
 
**code**

```
    import cv2 
    def vidPlay(): 
       cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
       ret, inputImage = cap.read() 
       if ret==True:
           return inputImage
       cap.release()
    a = vidPlay()
    print(a)
    print("done ")
    cv2.imshow(a)
```

**Error**

```
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yyy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\yyy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/yyy/Desktop/cameraPlay.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 
  File "C:\Users\yyy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**i tried different solutions on questions but not solve my issue.**

Comment: Please show your code, the line which throws the error

Comment: @MuhammadAsif  when i run the code this shows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)

Comment: i see that one but not solve my isssue @MuhammadAsif

Comment: What is the output of 'python -v'

Comment: python -v does not work on windows python.exe show the version Python 3.6.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150296/discussion-between-muhammad-asif-and-arslan-ahmad).

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a duplicate of the following question:

[DLL Load Failed Error when importing CV2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)

I'm copying the accepted answer from that question, for the ease:

> You can download the latest OpenCV 3.2.0 for Python 3.6 on Windows 32-bit or 64-bit machine, look for file starts withopencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m, from this unofficial site. Then type below command to install it:
>
> pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl (32-bit version)
>   pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl (64-bit
>   version) I think it would be easier.

*Written by: @thewaywewere*