# DLL Load failed error when installing opencv for Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv

I have python 3.6.3 32-bit version running on windows 10 64-bit machine.

[python version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXJ6p.png)

Since the opencv found on [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.4.1/opencv-3.4.1-vc14_vc15.exe/download) official website only supports python 2.7, I read [here](https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/) that I can use the following method to install opencv for python 3.6

However when I try to import cv2 in python, I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I also tried downloading opencv for python 3.6 from [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) unofficial site and following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2) instructions.

I am still getting the same error. Can somebody help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using 32-bit Python distribution on a 64-bit Windows machine, so it can't load IA 32-bit .dll on an AMD 64-bit platform.

Change  the Python distribution to a 64-bit one and hopefully it should work.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I upgraded to python 3.6.5 64 bit version. Updated my PATH variable aopennd re-installed numpy, matplotlib and OpenCV using pip install. It works now

Answer (score 0):

File "C:\Users\Muhammad Khan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mediapipe\python_*init*_.py", line 17, in 
from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util

Comment: how i can solve it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34463285)