# issues with python executable from pyinstaller

Tags: python, compiler-errors, exe, pyinstaller

I created an exe with pyinstaller (I'm using python 3.7.6 and pyinstaller 3.6) using

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icon.ico my_script.py
```

(the problem is the same even with `pyinstaller --onedir --icon=icon.ico my_script.py`)

the exe is built fine, but I get multiple errors along the way:

```
25484 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
25486 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
25487 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
25488 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
25490 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
25491 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
25496 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
25498 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
25499 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
26227 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
26524 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
26525 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
```

despite of these errors, the exe works fine on some computers, and on some of them don't. Where it doesn't work I get this error at startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "c:\users\valerio\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-pack
ages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[2800] Failed to execute script my_script
```

so my questions are:

1. why am I getting the built errors?
2. why on some computer is working fine and some dont's?? this second question is really driving me crazy..

thank you

Comment: PyInstaller is not cross platform - so if you compile on a (for example) Windows 10 64-bit machine and then try running on a Mac, Linux, or even Windows 32-bit it won't work properly, or at all.

Comment: @wstk i forgot to say that the other PCs are windows as well. Honestly I don't remember if they are 32 or 64 bit.. so what should I do to make it platform independent?

Comment: Unfortunately PyInstaller is just not cross platform. If you want to use the `.exe` on (say) MacOS, you need to compile it on MacOS.

Comment: ok but this problem happens on the same platform, so windows - windows. Of course I'm not expeting to use an EXE on a MacOs

Comment: Which windows versions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem. I write it here in case anyone needs it. 
the problem is just on windows server 2008 and 2012. They are missing a module called "desktop experience".

Once installed it (for example with [this](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2190/How-to-Install-Desktop-Experience-On-Windows-Server.html) guide) the error will disappear.

Another similar [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349669/dll-load-failed-when-import-cv2-opencv)