# DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, opencv, importerror, loadlibrary

I'm working on a CNN image classification project , and I'm using jupyter lab and python .
Well , I'm facing this problem and could not resolve it .
Ps : ( My windows edition is "Windows 10 Pro N" )[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq3eT.png)

I tried these two cmd "pip install opencv-python" & "pip install opencv-contrib-python" and i installed the dependencies manually .
Also the visual studio c++ is installed
But i get the same error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9hQF.png)

Comment: DO NOT install both packages. remove everything. install EXACTLY one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["DLL load failed" when import cv2 (opencv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349669/dll-load-failed-when-import-cv2-opencv)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask