# Unable to import cv2 using Anaconda 4.5 Python 3.6.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am currently new to python. I have installing python 3.6 using Anaconda version 4.5. After installing few packages below I am unable to import cv2:

```
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-learn jupyter
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

[image: Error Unable to import CV2]

I have tried installing various version of cv2 but none works.

Comment: try: `python -m pip install XXX`; or `use conda and switch env`

Comment: Tried the same it doesn't work. I think the problem is in init file line 2 where its written "from .cv2 import * " but in my cv2 folder there is no directory name cv2.

Comment: There shoud be a file named: `lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` on windows or `site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` on Linux if has been installed successfully.

Comment: Yes, this file is present with name cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd. The problem is in the import only, rest the package and conda is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when only conda and python are installed, activate the conda environment then use following command to install

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

OR

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

if you have R and Rstudio or multiple environments, there are chances of conflict of different versions of python.

Then you first have to activate the conda environment and run the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

that will take few minutes to install the opencv library.

Answer (score 1):

First, try again using the conda command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

A common mistake I personally did that caused this kind of problem is when you install the package in an environment but run jupyter from another one (like from the base environment).

I would suggest you:

1- use `conda list` in your environment to check the packages are correctly installed.

2- make sure the environment where you installed the packages is activate before running the command: `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried the same but the problem still persists. I think the problem is in __init__ file line 2 where its written "from .cv2 import * " but in my cv2 folder there is no directory name cv2.

Comment: check out the solutions stated here then: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)