# Anaconda: cannot find packages when calling Python interpreter from outside the shell

Tags: python, package, anaconda, python-import, intel-mkl

I have two Anaconda environments:

- The base environment
- An R environment (containing R only)

The base environment is the default environment and does not appear in the Anaconda subdirectory `envs`. Base is activated by default and in particular while the commands below are executed.

When I run python from within the Anaconda prompt (or another prompt that I have configured for Anaconda), importing `numpy` works without problems.

However, when I run my scrips from my IDE (exctuing `C:\my\path\to\Anaconda3\python.exe myscript.py`), the import of `numpy` fails. Therefore, I have installed `numpy` through pip and ended up with a broken installation. `import numpy` results now in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GoogleDrive\_Backup\Programmieren\Datathlon\econ_model.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

As far as I know the issue is due to different versions of numpy being used. (I *want* the mkl-enabled version, though).

That the right version of `numpy` is not found lets me guess that I have multiple python environments somehow and that the wrong one is called by my IDE. I have no idea how this can be possible, as Anaconda is the only python resource on my PC.

How can I call the right python version from outside of the anaconda prompt? How can I configure python/Anaconda that the correct version is called by default?

I am aware that activating the base environment solves the problem when working *within* a shell. But if I run a single command, i.e. just call the python script without opening a shell before, I cannot activate anything (can I?).

---

Techincal details:

- Python 3.7
- conda version 4.6.8 win-64
- Windows 10 64bit
- IDE: Eclipse with PyDev

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired activating the environments with a stack config? This allows my applications to use two different environments at the same time with different Python versions on each.

```
conda activate base && conda activate --stack myEnv
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours, so I used the following command under "Run as Administrator" in my command prompt, and everything works fine thereafter

```
set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `conda activate myEnvName`. Then, calling python on shell will bring you the desired python. When installing  packages, always select in which environment you wish it to be installed. The default environment is `base`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said, base *is* active and was active when I installed the packages. In fact, everything works within the base environment from the anaconda prompt. So what is wrong in the case I described?

Comment: Can you run it on shell and comment the output? `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)`

Comment: Sure. The output is `C:\my\path\to\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py`

Comment: try `pip uninstall numpy`, then `conda install numpy`. Avoid using pip when you have conda. Also, check this solution: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1508#issuecomment-463227581

Comment: I have completed `conda install numpy` before even trying pip. As I said, numpy works well within the shell, but does *not* work outside the shell.

Comment: after `pip uninstall numpy`, numpy is neither available within nor outside of the shell. `conda install numpy` tells me that numpy is already installed. I thus ran `conda remove numpy` and  `conda install numpy` again. The result is that numpy is not available anywhere still, but anaconda tells me the package is installed...

Comment: Try analyzing the difference between `import sys; print(sys.path)` in shell and inside you IDE.

Also, check the path `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\` if numpy is installed there.

Comment: `print(sys.path)` gives me exactly the same result when executed from within and outsinde of the shell.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974444/pydev-eclipse-not-loading-mklinit-when-run-from-a-conda-environment) can help. It should be a problem with pydev. I recommend switch to vscode if you can.

Comment: It is certainly not a PyDev issue, as the same problem occurs when I run the comman from cmd.exe or just use the run window (Win + R). I have now deleted and reinstalled Anaconda completely but run into other issues.