# Some applications including Anaconda Navigator and Command Prompt suddenly refuse to launch

Tags: windows, anaconda

After working in Anaconda's VS Code (and Microsoft C++ Build Tools), I restarted my computer. Afterwards, some applications, including Anaconda Navigator and Command Prompt, could not be opened anymore. I wanted to reinstall Anaconda Navigator, but even during uninstalling, I got the following error.

[image]

However, I proceeded and then installed Anaconda Navigator. Unfortunately even now, it would not open.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you update any software, or any windows update is interrupted?

Comment: @Immaturetrader No, Windows or other software were not updated during this time.

Comment: What I suggest are some random guesses, because I can't recreate the error on my system. 1. Try restarting, 2. Temporarily disable the windows defender and try reinstall, 3. If you can't access any other program as well, then load to a windows image backup is an option. else try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503705/fresh-re-install-of-anaconda-fails-remove-all-conflicts-between-anaconda-and-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many failed attempts at resolving the problem peacefully, I simply resetted Windows (Settings>System>Recovery>Reset this PC>Keep files), and now it works again.