# handwritten text recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, ocr

i am looking for any github project that can recognize some handwritten text so i can implement it into some project.

i come through this repo, and it seems really promising [here SimpleHTR](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR)

i downloaded all requirements including tensorflow
and i tried to run it using

```
python main.py
```

but it fails given me this weird error about tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Model import Model, DecoderType
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\Desktop\SimpleHTR-master\src\Model.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Abdelhamied\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

i've already tried to reinstall tensorflow, upgrade pip, overwrite msvcp140.dll in system32 folder but nothing is working

so can anyone help me!

Comment: i am also open for any new repo suggestions

Comment: Are you able to import tensorflow in Python in general?

Comment: no, it gives me the same error if i try to `import tensorflow`

Comment: Looks like tensorflow is not installed properly. I would first suggest that you install Anaconda, create new environment with python 3.5 and install tensorflow.

Comment: okay i'll try that and let you know

Comment: Are you sure you installed tensorflow properly? What is the version of tensorflow you tried to install/installed? Did you try installing earlier versions? Does your CPU support AVX?

Comment: I kind of faced same issue with OpenCV on windows. One solution was to use old version of opencv (<= opencv3.2),  and the other was 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2 (answer by Ramesh-X).
You can try the same thing with tensorflow or use older version like (pip install tensorflow==1.5), if thats's not an issue.

Comment: Ricky i installed tensorflow from requirements file included in the repo it version is 1.12

Comment: Garvita, i didn't installed anaconda but i installed tensorflow with pip `pip install tensorflow`