# conda install opencv ImportError: the specified module could not be found

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I installed opencv using the `conda` command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

The installation was successful without errors. Typing `conda list` also indicates opencv installed. But `import cv2` gives the error: `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`.

I note the opencv does not show up in the `Lib/site-packages` folder, but occurs in the `pkgs` folder, that is, `C:\\Anaconda\\Anaconda3.7\\pkgs\\opencv-4.1.1-py37h6afde12_1`. The `site-packages` folder has a file `cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`;

What is problem with the `import cv2` error? Was the conda-based opencv installation really successful? My python version is python3.7.1.

A similar problem has been reported here [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)

Comment: Pip installation seems a solution to the problem: https://medium.com/@shachindra/installing-opencv3-4-with-python3-on-windows10-5511e3323a0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install with pip. 'pip install opencv-python'

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the **contribution packages** of opencv?

Comment: I did not install the contribution packages yet. Does that matter?