# OpenCV installation using CMake

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

i have followed this video for OpenCV installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pYh1rFnNZs

Everything is built successfully in CMake, and I built and installed files using Visual Studio 2019 and everything was successful. But at last, when I opened command prompt, I have got this error:

```
C:\Users\Ganesh Akshaya>python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 79, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried Googling the error? It looks like several other people have had a similar issue, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43184887/3987854).

Comment: yeah i couldnt find any solutions even in that page people are installing using pip but here i installed using cmake and visual studio

Comment: i think the problem is with system paths could anyone tell me which system path i had missed ?

Comment: I would guess: probably the path at which Visual Studio built your cv2 DLLs

Comment: could you please tell me where can i find those paths

Comment: When you build in Visual Studio, the **full** path to the built DLLs is printed in the build window.

Comment: i found that dll,s are here in this path:

Comment: C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\bin

Comment: then tried keeping that directory in system path but its of no use the same error is repeating dll is missing!

Comment: seriosuly after 4 hours i found solution from the above mentioned path i copied all the dlls and saw available python paths in my environments and pasted in that python path! everything is set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seriosuly after 4 hours i found solution from the "C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\bin" path i copied all the dlls and saw available python paths in my environments and pasted in that python path "C:\Python38"