# How can i import cv2 on python 3.8

Tags: python, opencv

I am tryin to do a project that requires cv2 module. I downloaded the library through windows command prompt. `pip install cv2module` it installed successfully. but, when i try to import it on pycharm or python IDLE it throws an error like `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2

Answer (score 0):

Install contrib version opencv

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing missing DLL issue.

1. I deleted cv2 and openCV folder from the Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\ folder in my system.
   2.Installed Media feature pack on windows 10 from Optional features settings.
   3.Then ran pip install opencv-python again.
2. Rebooted my system and import cv2 worked like a charm.