# unable to import opencv

Tags: python, opencv, installation

I have minconda3 and python 3.8. I have been trying to install opencv through various ways and it is still not working.
I used:

```
pip install opencv
pip install opencv-python
conda install py-opencv
```

I tried installing using wheel but couldn't find a version that satisfied. I keep getting this error:

```
dll load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: OpenCV installation for Python using `conda`  <kbd>Super Easy ✨</kbd>

Try creating a new environment first. If you are using conda, it is better to use `conda install` whenever possible over `pip install`. You need to specify the channel `conda-forge` for opencv (it has the most updated version on conda).

The following command should do it.

```
conda create -n opencv_env python=3.8 -c conda-forge opencv numpy matplotlib scipy
```

Once installed, activate the environment with `conda activate opencv_env`.

However, for reproducibility, I would encourage you to create an `environment.yml` file and create/update the environment easily whenever necessary. See [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) for more details on it.

Save the following as `environment.yml` file. And then run `conda env create -f environment.yml` from the same location as the `environment.yml` file.

```yaml
### filename: environment.yml
#
### To create environment run:
#   conda env create -f environment.yml
#
### To update environment run:
#   conda env update -f environment.yml --prune
#
### Note: 
# The --prune option causes conda to remove any 
# dependencies that are no longer required from 
# the environment.
#
### Activating the environment
#   conda activate opencv_env
#
### Deactivating the environment
#   conda deactivate opencv_env


name: opencv_env # <-- The name of the environment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - opencv # -c conda-forge
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - scipy
  - pip:
    # list packages for which "pip install <package>" is necessary
    #- hypothesis
```

### References

- OpenCV package on anaconda from `conda-forge` channel: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv
- [Conda docs - *Creating an environment with commands*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)
- [Conda docs - *Creating an environment from an `environment.yml` file*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file)
- [Conda docs - *Creating an environment file manually*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually)

Comment: @FatimaArshad: Try this and let me know if you have any questions.