# Python OpenCV Installation - DLL error while importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I've been trying to set up OpenCV on my computer for the past 3 days and haven't able to install it.

I have tried different versions of Python and OpenCV but nothing seems to be working as I'm always getting an error:
DLL error while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

[image: Error Image]

Can someone help me to set up python, anaconda, OpenCV on my computer as I'm now completely frustrated as I've tried almost 30 different methods but in vain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest OpenCV 3.2.0 for Python 3.6 on Windows 32-bit or 64-bit machine, look for file starts withopencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m, from this unofficial site. Then type below command to install it:

pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl (32-bit version)
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl (64-bit version)
I think it would be easier.

Comment: I guess you forgot to mention the site - can you please mention it?

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: I've tried this already - it's not solving the error