# How to solve the import cv problem in vs studio?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, import, error-handling

> File "c:\Users\csany\Documents\PYTHON_BEGINEERS\read.py", line 1, in 
> import cv2 as cv
> File "C:\Users\csany\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
> from .cv2 import *
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Every time I try to run the code i get this error. I have installed OpenCV module through its source I have changed its path yet it still won't work in vs studio for python. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest OpenCV 3.2.0 for Python 3.6 on Windows 32-bit or 64-bit machine, look for file starts with`opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m`,  from this [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). Then type below command to install it:

- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` (32-bit version)
- `pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` (64-bit version)

I think it would be easier.

**Update on 2017-09-15:**

`OpenCV 3.3.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and replaced `OpenCV 3.2.0`.

**Update on 2018-02-15:**

`OpenCV 3.4.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and replaced `OpenCV 3.3.0`.

**Update on 2018-06-19:**

`OpenCV 3.4.1` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support, and replaced `OpenCV 3.4.0`.

**Update on 2018-10-03:**

`OpenCV 3.4.3` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support, and replaced `OpenCV 3.4.1`.

**Update on 2019-01-30:**

`OpenCV 4.0.1` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support.

**Update on 2019-06-10:**

`OpenCV 3.4.6` and `OpenCV 4.1.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support.

src : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43190144/13319197

Comment: WARNING: Requirement 'opencv_python~4.4.0~cp36~cp36m~win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: opencv_python~4.4.0~cp36~cp36m~win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.      And that's what I get when I use the command prompt in windows.

Comment: check the comment on answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43190144/13319197