# DLL Load Failed (Open cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

i tried many solutions for that error but didn't solved

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed right versions. Follow the below link for the compatible versions installed.
   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu
   https://www.drdataking.com/post/install-gpu-support-to-tensoflow-on-windows/
2. I was too getting similar issue:
   DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found[DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXjwk.png)
3. Solution was the environment variable path was not set properly. Please find the image below:
   [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Szsl.png)

Answer (score -1):

in python 3.8 i fixed a similar error when compiling with cxfreeze cv2 dll load failed ,
the problem was that i had another version of python 3.6 installed and although environment variable path from python 3.8 was first, cxfreeze still loaded opencv from python 3.6 causing the error in the output file,

I fixed it by moving python 3.6 to another location so not get detected by cxfreeze, be careful with the environments variable path if you have other versions of python installed when compiling.

try miniconda with Python 3.6 is more stable ,
https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/

Miniconda3-4.5.4 was the last Python 3.6 miniconda package.

Try to Install other versión of opencv

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Install media feature pack only if you use win10
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack

this article may interest you
[DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2)