# How to solve the Import Error of cv2 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I know that there are many questions and answers regarding this.
But I couldn't solve it.
I get

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

I have
Windows 11,
Python 3.9.12

opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66

PyCharm IDE

I tried

- installing Visual build tools

Comment: You may run into some problems running both of the opencv packages. Only have 1 installed at a time. The contrib package contains some more contributions than the other package. You should probably INSTALL: opencv-contrib-python, and UNINSTALL: opencv-python. Try running after doing my suggestion

Comment: after uninstalling opencv-python, I get the same error

Comment: Your question was asked on the opencv docs in FAQs section:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

There is also this stackoverflow thread with many responses:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2

You could also try using opencv-python instead of the contrib package

Did you install with pip or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV Python library is an Interface to C++ library, so in order to run the code, you should install the CMake.

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake build-essential libgtk-3-dev libboost-all-dev
```

If you are trying to run it in docker, just change the `$` to a `RUN` before install `requirements.txt`.

I hope this help you. Obs: I'm also using Windows 11 and WSL2. For me, it takes around 10 minutes to complete the apt and pip install, but worked for me.

Comment: CMake already installed