# Python Camelot ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, python-camelot

I have installed camelot which has installed opencv as its dependency on my windows 10 (Windows 10 Pro N).when trying to run my file for using camelot its giving the error:
"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found."

I have applied the first and second solutions mentioned on this page [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
however same error is appearing

the python version installed on my system is:3.9.5. And i haven't installed python through Annaconda.

the full traceback of the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\340bpython\newfile.py", line 1, in <module>    import camelot
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\camelot\__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from .io import read_pdf
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 5, in <module> from .handlers import PDFHandler
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 9, in <module> from .parsers import Stream, Lattice
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module> from .lattice import Lattice
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py", line 
25, in <module> from ..image_processing import (3, in <module> import cv2
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module> bootstrap()
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2") le
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)       
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module
 could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to also install cv2:

```
py -m pip install --user "camelot-py[base]" opencv-python
```